# NeedIndexError on upload

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am currently developing a project which makes use of google app engine. Running the application on my development server using *dev_app_server.py* works perfectly for me, but as soon as I upload the application online I get the following error:

```
NeedIndexError: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: Comment
  properties:
  - name: parent
  - name: date_created
    direction: desc
```

At first I thought it was because the Indexes still needed to be built as suggested by [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading) - but it has been days since I first uploaded the application and first got this error. Could anyone given an idea of what could be wrong or what I should look out for to solve this error?

For more details about the error you can access the page directly and see what I mean:
http://semiotic-karma-449.appspot.com/album/5741031244955648/view

**EDIT**
I put my index.yaml in a gist so that you can all take a look at it if it helps:

https://gist.github.com/KillaW0lf04/8283313

Comment: Make sure the existing index definition is exactly the same as what is suggested.  Seen a few people who think they are the same at first glance, but in fact are slightly different.

Comment: I copied and pasted the text provided and it still isnt working for me. Cant really understand whats going on

Comment: After doing that did you update index definitions with appcfg ?

Comment: Does appcfg.py update app.yaml do that or have I been oblivious about the availability of another command all this time?

Comment: argggh cant believe I didnt know update_indexes existed! Thanks for the help. Post your comment as a reply and ill accept it.

Comment: Once you make changes to index.yaml you need to update/push those index definitions up to the instance.  `appcfg update_indexes` or an `appcfg update` which will update the app and push any index definitions needs to be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you change/add/remove index definitions to `index.yaml` you need to update/push those index definitions up to the instance. `appcfg update_indexes` which just updates the indexes or  `appcfg update` which will update the app and push any index definitions needs to be run

Comment: With gcloud the command is gcloud preview datastore create-indexes index.yaml, where index.yaml is the index file generated by dev_appserver.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems clear: you need an index on the specified fields for the Comment model.

Indexes have to be specified in index.yaml. You should run that code in the dev server, which should automatically generate the entry in that file - but if it doesn't, you should add it manually (by copying/pasting the details from the error message). You'll need to re-deploy your app.